# Javascript function changing return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a function in my Node.js program which recives an array of products ids, then iterates through them to find the object in mongo and lastly if the object found is not in the array to be returned I push the object into it. I'm using a promise for handling asynchronous calls better.

The problem is that it sometimes returns two values and other times it returns only one value for the same input. I don't get why this is happening. I asume is due to asynchrony. Thanks in advance for help.

Here is the function.

```
    var productsToReturn = [];
    return new Promise((resolve , reject)=>{
        products.forEach(async (element, index)=>{
            var product = await Product.findOne({_id: element.productId}).exec();
            var indexOfArray = productsToReturn.findIndex(j=>JSON.stringify(j._id) ==JSON.stringify(product._id));
            if(indexOfArray === -1) productsToReturn.push(product);
            if(index -products.length === -1){
                resolve(productsToReturn);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Use `for...loop` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: You've created a race condition since the callback of the `forEach` method do not wait for each other, so the promise is resolved before all the pushing is done into the `productsToReturn` array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Terry,  then using traditional for loop would work as hoangdv has said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are multiple issues:

1. you use an async callback for forEach and manipulate a variable form the parent scope: `productsToReturn`. The order of execution depends on how fast `Product.findOne` returns and is therefore non-deterministic.
2. You resolve the promise from within the `forEach` callback function. That means when the first item is processed completely the result is being returned.

You could use a traditional `for` loop here as discussed in the comments. The downside would be, that the Products would be resolved one after another. If you want to run your queries in parallel (which might be the case looking at your code) you can use `map` instead of `forEach` and `Promise.all` to make sure everything completed.

The code would look something like this:

```
return Promise.all(
  products.map(async (element) =>
    Product.findOne({ _id: element.productId }).exec()
  )
);
```

If you actually have duplicate ids in your products array you might want to filter them beforehand to reduce the amount of queries needed. I'm not sure if that is the case or if the following line was just introduced while working on the issue of non deterministic return values:

```
var indexOfArray = productsToReturn.findIndex(j=>JSON.stringify(j._id) ==JSON.stringify(product._id))
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas looks like a good way to approach the problem while still having a good performance.